# Can I use a Click to Print button in an email newsletter?

Tags: javascript, printing, html-email

I'm wondering, is it possible to use a Click To Print button in an email newsletter?  Similar to the window.print() method, but I'm not sure if emails can contain javascript?

Comment: Emails should never contain javascript. It will get stripped and/or marked as spam by email clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so, and if it is, it's not advised.
I'm not sure if you tried Googling your question first, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561039/is-it-possible-recommendable-sending-html-emails-containing-javascript) out. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript).
You could redirect them to a webpage containing the javascript. That might work.

Comment: I did try googling it, but it was difficult to sort through results because the only wording I could think of made Google think I was looking for a way to print my email...  Thank you for this advice though!  I'm going to just put a link to a "Printer Friendly Version of the Email" and link that back to my site with the page there with trimmed down graphics and a print button there.  Thank you Very Much for all your help!

Comment: @Justgrant2009 Ahh, I see. And don't forget to accept answers as correct so that future people with the same question can find it easily. :) Good luck on your site!

Comment: No worries, I'm waiting the minimum time limit to mark this one as correct! Thanks!

Comment: @Justgrant2009 Anytime! Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

not that I can think of.

Alternative: Do you have the newsletter duplicated on your site for those that might "click here if you can't see this email correctly"?

You could add a querystring to the URL (http://www.mysite.com/newsletter1.htm?print=yes) then check the URL in javascript and fire off the window.print if the querystring is there.

?