# How to add click to print link in magento order confirmation newsletter?

Tags: magento

I want to add **click here** to print link in magento order confirmation newsletter.

How to do this?

I am trying this but not working for me

```
<a href="{{store url='sales/order/print/order_id/'}}""{{var order.id}}">Click here</a>to print
```

Comment: in which file you have written this code?

Comment: @KeyurShah In magento transnational email template

Comment: just look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491255/can-i-use-a-click-to-print-button-in-an-email-newsletter

Comment: @KeyurShah I dropped that feature to use

Comment: have you find any solution for that?

Comment: @KeyurShah what I was trying is to redirect the customer to siteurl/sales/order/print/order_id/id of order.But order_id/id  filed was truncating in the news letter ans even though this works first it will redirect the user to login.